# Image resolution decreases when uploading image to twitter using python tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using python tweepy library to update status on twitter. It is working fine but quality of image uploaded is not original.

I am using following statement to upload

```
api.update_with_media(filename=image, status=tags_str)
```

Original Image

[image: Here is my original image]

Uploaded Image

[image: Here is uploaded image]

Comment: What is the format and size of the uploaded image?

Comment: Have you tried manually appending the image to a tweet?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems you are facing.

The first is that Twitter returns a lower-resolution image unless you add `:orig` at the end.

For example, in your tweet, the embedded image is

- `https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DWiV8faXUAY6Aoy.jpg:thumb`

if there is a full resolution one available, it will be at

- `https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DWiV8faXUAY6Aoy.jpg:orig`

Secondly, Twitter turns all uploaded images into JPG - that's the cause of the weird effect around the text in your image.  The only way to prevent that it to make a section of your image transparent.  Because JPG cannot contain transparency, Twitter keeps your image in the original format.

The easiest way I've found of doing this to to include a 1 pixel high, full width, transparent line at the bottom of the image.  You will need to use a graphics editor to add a transparent section.

Comment: I am uploading image from local file system, my image file path is a local path not an URL. So `:orig` is not working. And what do you mean by `The easiest way I've found of doing this to to include a 1 pixel high, full width, transparent line at the bottom of the image`. Could you give me an example.

Comment: Can you post the URL of the tweet and I'll show you what I mean.